# Update Leagues and Teams in the ESPN app

Tags: apps

I downloaded the ESPN app from the windows phone marketplace.  When I first started the app it asked asked me to select the leagues and teams it shows on the live tile as well as when the app starts.

How can I change the leagues and teams?  I've looked through all the settings but can't seem to find the correct setting.

Thanks.

Comment: Which ESPN app? There are several when I search in my Marketplace...

Comment: It is the plain ESPN app.  Red and black live tile with white ESPN on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean [ESPN ScoreCenter](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/espn-scorecenter/486c5bc7-e253-e011-854c-00237de2db9e), then there is a settings icon (unconventionally) in the top right, which will take you to the mySports tab - swiping to the right takes you to the myTeams tab, and there is a link to "Add a Team". You can press and hold existing sports/teams on these tabs to bring up a context menu to delete them.